# AEM Column Control predefined columns

Tags: aem, sightly

You can provide column definitions by editing a Column Control component and using the following format:

[Number of Columns]  + ‘;’ + [Column Class] + ‘\t’ + [Format Label]

However, I don't want to give control to the author, not only that but if there are a set number of columns that we can support it would be nice if the Column Control comes with the required columns out of the box.

I tried to add the "layout" and "layouts" property but nothing is being detected by the component, however I can add X number of column controls as it is done in Geometrixx Outdoors but would like to have only one Column Control and allow the Author select which set of columns is needed.

/apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/colctrl

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible in CQ, but aem column controls work differently, mainly because of requirement related to sightly's ability to work with parsyses added to the page after creation. I agree that this isn't ideal, and I'm hoping there is an OOTB alternative coming (though there's no indication of this).